# Can I limit MongoDB specific query's resources? (CPU & RAM)

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql, resources, limit

I am trying to run a resource-hungry specific one-time query.
As I am aware of the option to limit MongoDB's used resources overall (RAM specifically), I was wondering if that can be done to a specific query (while specifying the maximum amount of resources that are allowed to be used, in the query itself, for example).

Is there such an option, or any similar solution that goes beyond the overall resource limit "scope" of MongoDB?